# Vue.js - multiple condition class binding

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, quasar

What is the proper way to bind class to a tag based on multiple conditions?

Given this tag, it seems that when trying to write multiple conditions one is being overwritten by another.

```
<q-tr :props="props" 
    :class=["(props.row.Name=='Row Name 1' || props.row.Name=='Row Name 2')?'text-bold':'bg-white text-black', (props.row.Name=='Row Name 3')?'text-green':'bg-white text-black']
>
</q-tr>
```

So in the above example `text-bold` class is overwritten by `bg-white text-black` since the second condition is overriding the first class binding.

Is there a way to structure conditions in `if, else if, else` style in vue class binding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind that class attribute to a computed property called `myClass` :

```
<q-tr
    :class="myClass"
>
</q-tr>
```

```
computed:{
   myClass(){
     if(this.props.row.Name=='Row Name 1' ){
         return 'text-bold';
      }
      else if( this.props.row.Name=='Row Name 3'){
         return 'text-green';
      }
      else{
           return 'bg-white text-black'
      } 

   }

}
```

Comment: This sort of makes sense but actually does not work. I get error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'row' of undefined`

Comment: Im not sure how should `props` be defines since its passed to the component there